# unit and proper divisor of zero in a ring

Tags: ring-theory

**unit and proper divisor of zero**

A unit in a ring R cannot be a proper divisor of zero.

1. Let x ∈ R be a unit.
2. Hence there exists a y ∈ R such that x · y = y · x = 1.
3. Suppose x · w = z for some w ∈ R.(z is an additon identity)
4. y · (x · w) = y · z = z.
5. On the other hand, y · (x · w) = (y · x) · w = 1 · w = w.
6. As w = z, x is not a proper divisor of zero.

but in respect of the final statement, the difinition about a proper zero divisor is that a is a proper divisor of zero if a != z and there exists a
b != z such that a · b = z or b · a = z(z is an addition identity, too). I think the statement, "if P(b != z) , then Q(a is a proper zero divisor)", is not equal to the other statement, "if not P(b = z), then not Q(a is not a proper zero divisor)". Or maybe I misunderstand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just proven that it is impossible to get $xw=0$ except in the trivial way with $w=0$.  (I.e. $x$ is not a left zero divisor.)

By a symmetric argument, it is impossible to get $wx=0$ unless $w=0$. ($x$ is not a right zero divisor.)

The right zero divisors do not always equal the left zero divisors, so it is necessary, in principal, to note both points.